# Does Arch come with a GUI preinstalled?

Tags: archlinux, gui

I know that, for some people, this may seem like an obvious question, but, as a former user of the desktop version of Arch Linux (which came without GUI preinstalled), I have to ask: does the Raspberry Pi version of Arch come with Xorg/Xfree86 installed?

Comment: InkBlend -- honestly -- if you are this hung up about the presence of a GUI that you're not going to use anyway, for your own sake explain why this matters at all.  This is a common (and misplaced) fixation, if you don't have a serious (and rational) reason to be concerned about whether X exists on your system, *move on and forget about it*.

Comment: Personally I have not seen this question here, so might as well leave it. Plus if someone else asks this question, we can refer them here.

Comment: @InkBlend : No, like Vincent says it is a legitimate question, and you did get an answer.  Arch always begins with a minimal base, I believe.  I just wanted to point out that that alone (no GUI!) is not a very good reason to consider re-installing, because it's a trivial difference.  I do understand where you are coming from, BTW, which is why I mentioned all this.  Pretty sure I have been pre-occupied the same way before ;)

Comment: @goldilocks, who said anything about "not using a GUI" or "re-installing"?

Comment: Probably in relation to this question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/how-can-i-remove-the-gui-from-raspbian-debian from the same day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to install a GUI. According to [this page on eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions#Arch), Arch for the RPi does not come pre-installed with a GUI.

To install any GUI with Arch, either just search the internet or use the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/)

Here is how to install LXDE:

```
pacman -S openbox lxde gamin dbus   #Lxde and needed dependancies
pacman -S xorg-server xorg-xinit xorg-server-utils   #Xorg
pacman -S mesa xf86-video-fbdev xf86-video-vesa   #Video Drivers
#To use startx, you will need to define LXDE in your ~/.xinitrc file:
echo “exec ck-launch-session startlxde” >> ~/.xinitrc
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Arch Wiki. The Wiki has to be the best documentation for a distribution I have ever come across.

Answer (score 2):

XFCE is a graphical desktop, and the instructions I used for putting it on the Raspberry Pi are here: http://blog.adityapatawari.com/2013/05/arch-linux-on-raspberry-pi-running-xfce.html

At the bottom of that page is a one-liner that makes it easy:

> To save you some time, I have combined these commands in a small shell
>   script and put it on github (fork it). So now, to install XFCE on your
>   Pi, you need to fire just one command:
>
> `curl
>   https://raw.github.com/adimania/arch-desktop-environments/master/XFCE-Arch-RPi.sh
>   | bash`

Comment: Use `curl -k ...` to avoid the SSL error...

Answer (score 2):

No, Arch doesn't come with a desktop environment. Why, because whats the fun in having one pre-installed. The point in Arch is, to build it yourself.