# How can I remove the GUI from Raspbian/Debian?

Tags: raspbian, xorg, gui

I would like to know how to *completely* remove X.org and all GUI-related components from Raspbian or soft-float Debian.  The most obvious solution would be `sudo apt-get purge xorg`, but I am afraid that that will leave some GUI packages lying around.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I answered this in another similar question:
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4745/how-to-uninstall-x-server-and-desktop-manager-when-running-as-headless-server

Answer:
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5127/6199

Comment: An additional reason to remove the gui is so that updates run faster, because fewer packages require update.

Comment: Well, now there is Jessie Lite!

Comment: +1 to @Michael. The main reason to remove the GUI is it takes 98% less resources to keep your system up to date.

Answer (score 68):

I was able to remove the desktop environment include with Raspbian by first removing `x11-common` and then removing my 'stale' packages.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge x11-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

Comment: Two liner magic!

Answer (score 34):

You can do it on your own, or use what others have already done for you:

- [84 MB Minimal Raspbian ARMHF Image for Raspberry Pi](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/07/31/84-mb-minimal-raspbian-armhf-image-for-raspberry-pi/)
- [109 MB Raspbian Wheezy armhf Raspberry Pi minimal image](http://www.linuxsystems.it/2012/06/raspbian-wheezy-armhf-raspberry-pi-minimal-image/)
- [222 MB Hexxeh image](http://www.raspbian.org/HexxehImages)

Comment: +1 While the autoremove option is quick and dirty and does work, I find that a clean install without the GUI works better and the footprint is smaller.

Comment: This really is the best answer for most situations where SD card space is scarce.

Comment: @kenny: For even less SD card space you might want to take a look at Tiny Core Linux for Pi.

Answer (score 17):

`$ sudo apt-get --purge remove "x11-*"`

This will remove all the packages that are under x11 which is the library with all the graphical packages. the option --purge allow you to delete all the config file related.

`$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`
autoremove removes all the unused packages. There are a lot of unused packages after the first command.

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. You simply provided two commands and no explanation. Please, in the future, explain your answers so that users who are new can understand what you mean. You should explain what these commands are for.

Comment: Weeeell, sorry.
So : apt-get --purge remove x11-* will remove all package that are under x11, which is the library with all the graphical package.
Then, apt-get --purge autoremove will remove all package that are not used anymore.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly how an answer should be, provide the commands *as well as* an explanation. That's all I was trying to get you to do. Thanks!

Comment: It is dangerous to use wildcard without quotes. If there are any files or directories beginning with "x11-" in your current directory, they're going to get passed to apt-get, because your shell tries to look for matching files by your wildcard. Quoting it passes the asterisk directly to apt-get: `$ sudo apt-get --purge remove "x11-*"`

Answer (score 13):

The way I've done it is to remove all the packages under the `Installed Packages --> x11` category in `aptitude`, then run `sudo apt-get autoremove`, which uninstalls any leftover packages that aren't needed anymore.

Comment: Would you mind adding the exact aptitude command that you would use to remove the X packages?

Comment: i just ran the aptitude TUI (text user interface), so `sudo aptitude`, then, using the arrow keys, scrolled to the `x11` section and removed each package with the `-` key

Answer (score 10):

The GUI packages are referenced by the meta-package `task-desktop`. So it is enough to remove that meta-package:

```
sudo apt-get remove task-desktop
```

I found out the name of the package by running Debian-specific tasksel:

```
tasksel --list-tasks
tasksel --task-packages desktop
```

Comment: Package 'task-desktop' is not installed, so not removed...

Comment: `tasksel remove desktop` seems to be the way to do it but it doesn't do anything.  A curses screen pops up and then goes away.

Answer (score 7):

There is now also an X-less image by the foundation named `Raspbian Jessie Lite`: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

And if you want an installer which installs only a minimal system, there's also the [Raspbian UnAttended Netinstaller](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst)

Answer (score 5):

Jessie Raspbian took a different but similar path as other answers here.

```
# First the jre needs X (boo!) so switch that out to a headless version
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless

# Next x11 won't go because libice6 is installed
# but this seems to trigger the same result
sudo apt-get remove -y libice6

# Finally clean up
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge
```

While I'm at it, cleaning up for headless mode:

```
# you can also create this blank file after you
# burn your image to the SD card
touch /boot/ssh

sudo raspi-config
   3. Boot Options
      - B1 Desktop / CLI
        - B1 Text console, requiring user to login
        - Press Enter
      - Tab over to Finish
      - Yes to Reboot

# switch users, get rid of default password in a way
sudo useradd -G sudo -m your_new_username
sudo passwd your_new_username
sudo userdel -r pi
```

Headless server!

Comment: ```openjdk-11-jre-headless``` in Raspbian Buster

Answer (score 4):

Build a custom image? - I use https://github.com/jamesbennet/pistrap. A fairly minimal install is ~300mb.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ apt-get --purge remove 'x11-*'
$ apt-get --purge autoremove
```

The first command removes many X11 packages, including the X11 core libraries. Since all other X11 packages (transitively) depend on the X11 core libraries, they are also removed.

The second command removes all [now unneeded packages](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-get), i.e. packages that were only installed as a dependency of later removed packages.

The `--purge` options instructs `apt-get` to also remove the related configuration files.

On non-minimal install this frees up about 1.5 GiB space.

Comment: It is the exact same answer I gave.

Comment: @vcuongvu, no, it is not. My explanation is different, i.e. better and more extensive. I also give an estimate on how much space will be freed. I addressed this because some readers of the question apparently have doubts if the removal is actually worth it. Btw, I upvoted your answer because it contains the right commands.

Comment: My bad then, I'm unable to remove my downvote unless you edit a little bit your answer. However, I think it would be less redundant to comment under my answer in that case.

Comment: This answer is actually better and safer because the asterisk-containing argument is properly quoted.

Answer (score 1):

to remove gnome

```
# tasksel remove gnome-desktop
```

Tasksel is a tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated “task” onto your system.

```
# apt-get install aptitude tasksel
```

Install gnome on debian

```
# tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```

http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html

Comment: this does not actually answer the question, because there's no "gnome" on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @lenik That's not true. Gnome is available, try `apt-cache search gnome`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my RPi. Using `aptitude purge` instead of `apt-get purge` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get remove -y --purge x11-common
apt-get autoremove -y --purge
apt-get install -y deborphan
deborphan | xargs dpkg -P # do this a bunch of times

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).