# Customize GUI-less session

Tags: raspbian

I want to [remove the GUI from Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/how-can-i-remove-the-gui-from-raspbian-debian) and then customize it:

- White background or background image
- Image in down-right corner
- Change font size/font/font color
- Center align text

Is that possible? And how could I do this?

Comment: For the image, you could just write the raw bitmap data strait to the framebuffer. 
Could you describe what you need it for. As to me it looks like you are trying to build a digital signage application. My guess is that there are better solutions for this, than styling the console.

Comment: @Gerben How can I do that? (writing raw bitmap data to framebuffer)

Comment: Convert the bitmap to raw RGB data. Then write it to `/dev/fb0`. I added the image to the top, and over the entire length, so I could just do `cat 720x80-banner.raw > /dev/fb0`. Since you want it at the bottom, you'd have to write from a certain offset in the framebuffer. If you only want the right, you'd have to write line, by line  to the fb.

Comment: @Gerben I'm sort of a noob, sorry. How do I write an offset in the framebuffer?

Comment: I'm a noob my self. But I think you can use `dd` for that. Something like `dd if=/home/pi/banner.raw skip=$offset count=$datalength of=/dev/fb0`. PS here is the html5 webpage I made to generate raw bitmap data files: http://gerben.algemeenbekend.nl/tmp/canvas-raw.html

Comment: You can answer your own question for other people to use.

Comment: @ppumkin I haven't found an answer, I just have changed my mind and don't want it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a partial success with `setterm`:

```
Usage:
 setterm [options]

Options:
 -term <terminal_name>
 -reset
 -initialize
 -cursor <on|off>
 -repeat <on|off>
 -appcursorkeys <on|off>
 -linewrap <on|off>
 -default
 -foreground <black|blue|green|cyan|red|magenta|yellow|white|default>
 -background <black|blue|green|cyan|red|magenta|yellow|white|default>
 -ulcolor <black|grey|blue|green|cyan|red|magenta|yellow|white>
 -ulcolor <bright blue|green|cyan|red|magenta|yellow|white>
 -hbcolor <black|grey|blue|green|cyan|red|magenta|yellow|white>
 -hbcolor <bright blue|green|cyan|red|magenta|yellow|white>
 -inversescreen <on|off>
 -bold <on|off>
 -half-bright <on|off>
 -blink <on|off>
 -reverse <on|off>
 -underline <on|off>
 -store >
 -clear <all|rest>
 -tabs < tab1 tab2 tab3 ... >      (tabn = 1-160)
 -clrtabs < tab1 tab2 tab3 ... >   (tabn = 1-160)
 -regtabs <1-160>
 -blank <0-60|force|poke>
 -dump   <1-NR_CONSOLES>
 -append <1-NR_CONSOLES>
 -file dumpfilename
 -msg <on|off>
 -msglevel <0-8>
 -powersave <on|vsync|hsync|powerdown|off>
 -powerdown <0-60>
 -blength <0-2000>
 -bfreq freqnumber
 -version
 -help
```

And the font changes can be accomplished with:

```
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Greek-Fixed16.psf
```

however I still don't understand what did you mean by "center text".

Comment: I mean Center Alignment. Edited now to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. However I don't see anything for an image in the corner there, let's hope someone else knows.