# Arch Linux ARM doesn't boot to desktop

Tags: boot, archlinux

I was installed Arch Linux ARM, and when i got to start RPi, start with command lines, and next ask me the password and user name, i put it then i press enter, but just show up a  line with my last login and next more 3 lines where the last say that graphical was been loaded, but keep in command line mod and not change.
Someone now how to fix it and jump to desktop main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to install a graphical environment (X11-Server, GUI like Gnome, KDE, LXDE, XFCE, etc) on the raspberry pi in order to get a desktop environment which can be started on startup or later via `startx`. You could check [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_Environment) and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_Guide#Choose_and_install_a_graphical_interface) out.
Arch Linux is a distribution which addresses advanced users instead of "normal" users.
You could also check [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5257/does-arch-come-with-a-gui-preinstalled) for more information (it's basically the same as the links above).

Answer (score 2):

It's not supposed to boot into a desktop environment. Arch Linux is recommended for advanced users. If you want to try out the different distros available on the Raspberry Pi I recommended trying berryboot. It can be installed easily without a disk imager and it has a graphical menu you can use to download new images (as many as you can store on your SD card) and select which one to boot. It even has USB drive support to hold your images.

http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot

Comment: I already know berryboot, and i won't install it because my RPi arrive without ethernet serial, why i dont know and i can't put internet on it.